# Installing an old version of gcc on linux-redhat

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat

In order to compile an old-compiler I am using the gcc that is installed in my machine (gcc version 4.4.6).

The gcc v 4.4.6 compiler isn’t supporting some syntaxs that are in the old-compiler files and is issuing errors like : lvalue required as left operand, error: attempt to use poisoned...and so on.

the last time someone has compiled that old compiler they used gcc version 2.96.
So I downloaded some older version of gcc (3.0 – didn’t found 2.96) and try to build binaries from it.

However – my machines are x86_64 and the 3.0 compiler issuing an error :

> Configuration x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu not supported

naturally - no x86_64 existed way back in those days.
any advise will be welcome.

**update** :
I have installed on vertualBox an old redhat version (5.7) that came with an old gcc compiler (3.4.6) and tried to compile the cross compiler.My host is - i386-redhat-linux. Now , I didn't get this message and the compilation of the cross compiler started, BUT, when it came to compile unwind-dw2.c file I got the next assembler error :

```
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:259: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r11,low(r0,.L47),r11'
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:736: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r3,low(r0,.L327),r3'
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:1226: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r3,low(r0,.L317),r3'
/tmp/ccAk3sX0.s:1739: Error: unrecognized instruction `addi r3,low(r0,.L412),r3'
```

So I am stuck again ...

Comment: Avoid doing that. Or run an old 32 bits Linux distribution in a `chroot`-ed environment. BTW, what exactly is the "old compiler" you are compiling???

Comment: trying to build a cross compiler. the compiler is based on an old version of gcc (3.0). I thought that I need to install some kind of lib's... I think that the machines support 32 bit - but I am not sure. will check this however I don't think that installing an old version on linux is needed...

Comment: Any reason for not using a recent GCC (e.g. version 4.8) cross-compiler???

Comment: The reason is that I have old cross compiler sources that I need to compile in order to use the cross compiler bins. later on I will update those sources to the latest ones...

Comment: No, compile a recent cross compiler ... (e.g. compile GCC 4.8 from its source code, as a cross-compiler)

Comment: but the old compiler has modifications (machine description and probably more changes that I don't know of) that other people do that I need. If I will take the latest gcc those changes will be lost. Do you think it is a waste of time trying to get this old compiler sources compile again ?

Comment: Yes it is a waste of time, and you won't find anyone to help you.... Please tell exactly what ancient cross-compiler (including version) and for what exact target, you want to build ....

Comment: updated my progress above

Answer (score 0):

Install a really old Linux distribution in a virtual machine.

Comment: please see my comment for Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: feel free to waste your time on unnecessary stuff.

Comment: OK - are you sure this is the only way ? can you elaborate a bit more about why it doesn't work if the machines do support 32 bit ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's easier to install old distribution than to to ply with the current one.
But if you have plenty of time you can try to find and install all needed dependencies. By the way risking with stability of current OS installation.